# React Native ios build folder outside of project root

Tags: react-native

When I run `react-native run-ios --verbose` I see that my app is created at

`/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ztrewhgfdsjtizchezgdoiujklztre/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app`

instead of `ios/build` inside my project root.

I have been searching for ways to configure this inside `react-native.config.js` but could not find how to explictly stated in the docs.

This is my `react-native.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ["./assets/fonts/"],
}
```